# Is it possible to specify the compression when using pyarrow write_dataset?

Tags: parquet, partitioning, pyarrow

I would like to be able to control the type of compression used when partitioning (default is snappy).

```
import numpy.random
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

data = pa.table(
    {
        "day": numpy.random.randint(1, 31, size=100),
        "month": numpy.random.randint(1, 12, size=100),
        "year": [2000 + x // 10 for x in range(100)],
    }
)


ds.write_dataset(
    data,
    "./tmp/partitioned",
    format="parquet",
    existing_data_behavior="delete_matching",
    partitioning=ds.partitioning(
        pa.schema(
            [
                ("year", pa.int16()),
            ]
        ),
    ),
)
```

It is not clear to me, from the doc, if that's actually possible

Comment: yes..should be possible. checkout - pyarrow.dataset.ParquetFileFormat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to [specify](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset) the [file options](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.ParquetFileFormat.html#pyarrow.dataset.ParquetFileFormat.make_write_options).

**file_options**

> pyarrow.dataset.FileWriteOptions, optional
>
> FileFormat specific write options, created using the FileFormat.make_write_options() function.

You can use any of the compression options mentioned in the docs - snappy, gzip, brotli, zstd, lz4, none

Below code writes dataset using **brotli** compression.

```
import numpy.random
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

data = pa.table(
    {
        "day": numpy.random.randint(1, 31, size=100),
        "month": numpy.random.randint(1, 12, size=100),
        "year": [2000 + x // 10 for x in range(100)],
    }
)


file_options = ds.ParquetFileFormat().make_write_options(compression='brotli')

ds.write_dataset(
    data,
    "./tmp/partitioned",
    format="parquet",
    existing_data_behavior="delete_matching",
    file_options=file_options,
    partitioning=ds.partitioning(
        pa.schema(
            [
                ("year", pa.int16()),
            ]
        ),
    ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know where valid parquet write options are documented?